# Why is delta used to describe difference between two entities

Tags: definition

I hear a lot about extracting "delta" between two properties in my current job. I come from a User Interface programming background and I do not really have much math background. I looked up delta online but did not find any definition of it meaning "difference"

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: $\Delta$ifference.

Comment: Probably, as Simon says, just because both words start with "d".

Comment: The Greek word for difference also starts with delta: διαφορά (lower case) or Διαφορά (upper case). This might have been the historical motivation for using Δ and δ this way.